# fish shell shows error in piping - new error

Tags: fish, omf

[image]I am getting multiple errors from shell init scripts which more or less seem the same:

~/.local/share/omf/pkg/z/functions/z.fish (line 11): Expected a string, but instead found a pipe

' bash $argv ^| read -l Z_PWD

I looked at all the files that are generating these errors and none of them has changed in months, if not years - though I can see the offensive line.

```
%> /usr/bin/fish --version                                                                           
Sat 22:15
fish, version 3.1.2
```

### EDIT:
Added a screen capture of what I see everytime I fork a shell.

If you have some thoughts on what gives and how I can fix it, appreciate it.

Thanks!

Cheers; 'best,
shankar

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the z plugin for Oh My Fish, to pick up [this commit](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/plugin-z/commit/ecdeaea6b0db9074b8444a50a7087df8e24eb9e7):

```
omf update z
```

Comment: I pulled in that change. Curious this change from 2019 did not hit me till this week - likely something else changed somewhere and I have not been able to catch that!  And worse, now I get this:~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish (line 609): Expected a string, but instead found a pipe
  switch (python --version ^| tr '\n' ' ')
                            ^
from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish
        called on line 1 of file /opt/anaconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/config.fish
        called during startup
...